# backbone and underscore template rendering

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm trying to use backbone to show on a page the result from an API call, I would like to iterate over the collection and create one entry for every element of the collection within my html. It seems I'm missing something cause I see the template tag rendered but none of my items are there. What's the problem with my code?

here the html

```
<div class="form-group" id="main">
 <% _.each(collection, function(car) { %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" /><%= car.get("model") %>
  </div>
 <% }); %>
</div>
```

and here js

```
var CarView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#main",
    template: _.template($("#main").html()),
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template({collection: [{id:1, model:"ford"}, {id:2,model:"kia"}]}));
        return this;
    }
});

var carView = new CarView();
```

here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e5hg6rzp/3/

Comment: Your code, working with barely any modifications: https://jsfiddle.net/962djtp1/ -- i should state: please move your template into a <script>

Comment: @JavierBuzzi thanks, looking through your fiddle helped me fix mine and now everything seems to work very well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I suggest you to keep your template in `<script type='text'/template> ... </script>` tag. Secondly you are using `.get()` method inside your template on plain objects which are do not have this method. In your example you can access property through a `.` -

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" /><%= car.model %>
  </div>
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjz2qh13/)

If you want to use `Backbone.Collection` when you should create `Car Collection` and `Car Model`:

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    model: "ford"
}, {
    id: 2,
    model: "kia"
}];

var CarView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#main",
    template: _.template($("#templ").html()),
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        return this.$el.html(this.template(new CarCollection(data)))
    }
});

var CarModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: '',
        model: ''
    }
})

var CarCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: CarModel
})

var carView = new CarView();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-inline panel panel-default">
    <div class="form-group" id="main">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type='text/template' id='templ'>
  <% _.each(models, function(car) { %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" />
      <%= car.get('model') %>
    </div>
    <% }); %>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I put the template tags and I'm rendering my collection now with `.toJSON()` method, I can access objects attributes. I needed to add some other stuff like rendering the view after the collection is reset. Now everything seems just right.

Comment: @MattiaProcopio please check answer as correct if it was helpful, thanks.